# sed unintentionally wipes remainder of line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Attempting to locate a variety of similar incidents within a file.

```
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB0' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB1' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB7' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address type='bmu' domain='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB9' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB4' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
```

I'm *attempting* to simply locate any instance beginning with `PCOIP_` and replace that string with `0x86`

The **result** will look like:

```
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address type='bmu' domain='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
```

The command I'm trying currently which handles replacing the necessary string, except it also wipes the remainder of that entire line:

```
sed s/PCOIP_\(.*\)/0x86/g' file
```

The command **as is** makes the file look like:

```
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86
<address type='bmu' domain='0x000' bus='0x86
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86
```

Comment: Try `sed "s/PCOIP_\([^']*\)/0x86/g" file`

Comment: Wiktor's answer is good, but does not explain the underlying problem: Your `.*` grabs not only the remaining `bus` value, but *everything* up until the next newline. All that gets replaced with `0x86`. So you need to make your search term match *only* that **part** of the line you actually want to rerplace, no more. Wiktor has showcased how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed "s/PCOIP_[^']*/0x86/g" file
```

Here, `PCOIP_[^']*` matches `PCOIP_` and then any zero or more chars other than a `'` char. The whole match is replaced with `0x86` substring.

See an online demo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB0' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB1' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB7' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address type='bmu' domain='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB9' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='PCOIP_USB4' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />"
sed "s/PCOIP_[^']*/0x86/g" <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address type='bmu' domain='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
<address DOMAIN='0x000' bus='0x86' slot='0x00' function '0x0' />
```